# How to subset a SpatialPoints object to get the points located on each side of a SpatialLines object using R?

Tags: r, point, line, sp, rgeos

I need to subset the *SpatialPoints* object to get the points located in the **left** or in the **right** side of the *SpatialLines* object (red line, see figure below).

This is the code example in `R`:

```
# Load packages
library('sp')

# Load projection
epsg.32721 <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

# Load data and create Spatial objects

# Sample points data
x <- c(790115.1, 790141.3, 790130.6, 790122.2, 790132.0, 790116.0, 790119.1, 790135.7, 790117.9, 790111.0, 790141.0, 790111.2, 790134.9, 790115.1, 790110.9, 790138.5, 790111.7, 790138.8, 790125.5, 790134.3, 790137.5, 790114.7, 790135.9, 790135.7, 790119.4)
y <- c(6193520, 6193460, 6193490, 6193470, 6193506, 6193511, 6193512, 6193480, 6193513, 6193474, 6193467, 6193505, 6193472, 6193507, 6193515, 6193503, 6193503, 6193482, 6193489, 6193496, 6193470, 6193508, 6193517, 6193464, 6193483)

# Sample points to SpatialPoints object
sampleSpatialPoints <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x,y), proj4string = epsg.32721)

# Line data
x2 <- c(790100.0, 790120.7, 790145.7, 790134.6, 790135.2, 790154.1)
y2 <- c(6193451, 6193475, 6193480, 6193497, 6193516, 6193543)

# Line points to SpatialLines object
lineSpatialLines <- SpatialLines(LinesList = list(Lines(slinelist = list(Line(coords = cbind(x2,y2))), ID = "1")), proj4string = epsg.32721)

# Plot
plot(sampleSpatialPoints, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", pch = 19)
plot(lineSpatialLines, pch = 19, col = "red", add = TRUE)
box()
```

[image: figure example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question defining two *SpatialPolygons* objects from the *SpatialLines* object coordinates and the *SpatialLines* object bounding box `bbox()`. After that, I made an intersect between the *SpatialPoints* object and the two *SpatialPolygons*. See code and figure below.

**Note:** I had to load the `rgeos` package to use the function `gIntersects`.

```
# Load packages
library('rgeos')

# Add offset (optionally)
offsetX <- 0
offsetY <- 20

coords <- rbind(c(bbox(lineSpatialLines)['x','max'] + offsetX, bbox(lineSpatialLines)['y','max'] + offsetY),
                c(bbox(lineSpatialLines)['x','min'] - offsetX, bbox(lineSpatialLines)['y','max'] + offsetY),
                as.data.frame(coordinates(lineSpatialLines))
)

coords2 <- rbind(c(bbox(lineSpatialLines)['x','max'] + offsetX, bbox(lineSpatialLines)['y','min'] - offsetY),
                 c(bbox(lineSpatialLines)['x','min'] - offsetX, bbox(lineSpatialLines)['y','min'] - offsetY),
                 as.data.frame(coordinates(lineSpatialLines))
)

# Coords to SpatialPolygons objects
polySide1 <- SpatialPolygons(Srl = list(Polygons(srl = list(Polygon(coords = coords)), ID = "1")), proj4string = epsg.32721)
polySide2 <- SpatialPolygons(Srl = list(Polygons(srl = list(Polygon(coords = coords2)), ID = "2")), proj4string = epsg.32721)

# Subset SpatialPoints in Side1
pointsInSide1 <- which(gIntersects(spgeom1 = polySide1, spgeom2 = sampleSpatialPoints, byid = TRUE))
sampleSpatialPointsSide1 <- sampleSpatialPoints[pointsInSide1, ]

# Subset SpatialPoints in Side2
pointsInSide2 <- which(gIntersects(spgeom1 = polySide2, spgeom2 = sampleSpatialPoints, byid = TRUE))
sampleSpatialPointsSide2 <- sampleSpatialPoints[pointsInSide2,]

# Subset SpatialPoints over line 
pointsOverLine <- which(gIntersects(spgeom1 = lineSpatialLines, spgeom2 = sampleSpatialPoints, byid = TRUE))
sampleSpatialPointsOverLine <- sampleSpatialPoints[pointsOverLine, ] # NULL

# Plot
plot(polySide1, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", col = "grey30")
plot(polySide2, col = "grey70", add = TRUE)
plot(sampleSpatialPoints, pch = 19, add = TRUE)
plot(lineSpatialLines, pch = 19, col = "red", add = TRUE)
plot(sampleSpatialPointsSide1, col = "orange", add = TRUE)
plot(sampleSpatialPointsSide2, col = "green", add = TRUE)
box()
```

[image: figureAnswer]

Orange points are in **Side1** and green points are in **Side2**.

Comment: Nice solution. What is the optional offset for?

Comment: In the case you have some points that have an extent higher or lower than the extent of the **SpatialLines** object you can add this _xy offset_ to ensure that all the points will be over one polygon.